# SQL Server. DataType for password hash (sha 512)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, password-hash

Wondering which data type to select for my SQL Server to store the sha512 password hash. (hashed value will always have fixed length)

```sql
 declare @hashedPasswd varchar(max)
 set @hashedPasswd = convert(varchar(max), HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'any password with any langth'), 1)
 select len (@hashedPasswd)
```

always returns length of 130.

What is the best choice for datatype of the column?
Variants are nvarchar(max), nvarchar(130), varchar, char.
If I understand correctly, nvarchar is a waste of space in my case, because It will be only ASCII symbols in hashed value.

Please assist.

Comment: Why are you using a `varchar` at all? `HASHBYTES` returns a `varbinary` with a length of up to 8000.

Comment: sha_512 is the hashing algorithm. As I understand, hashed value will always be 130 symbols

Answer (score 1):

SHA2_512 is 64 bytes long and internaly a varbinary so I would suggest using this datatype instead.
For more safty I also would recommend to use an additional salt for password encryption and decryption. You can find a useful description here:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4037/storing-passwords-in-a-secure-way-in-a-sql-server-database/

Best regards, Stephan

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql), `hasbytes` returns a `varbinary` therefore your data type is `varbinary`.

Your length of 130 is only because you are casting to a varchar and is an inefficient way to store it. From the documentation, sha512 returns **64 bytes**, therefore your length required is 64.

```
 declare @hashedPasswd varbinary(max)
 set @hashedPasswd = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'any password with any length')
 select len (@hashedPasswd)
```